# Perl not able to write to a file handle in child process

Tags: perl

I need to write some data to a file handle in child. file handle was created in parent before forking. This is because I can read data from the file handle in parent since fork keeps the file handles and locks on them if any, shared between parent and child. This is to share the data in parent and child working both on linux and windows platforms. I was able to to data sharing using IPC::Shareable in linux and this does not work in windows due to unavailability of semaphore.pm in windows [windos does not support semaphore.pm], So for windows I tried Win32::MMF which was crashing my perl compiler.

So with the file handle approach, IO write is not happening in child. Please look in to the below code

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "creating file\n"; 
open FH, ">testfile.txt" or die "cant open file: $!\n";
close FH;

my $pid = fork();

if ( $pid == 0 )
{
print "entering in to child and opening file for write\n";
open FH, ">>testfile.txt" or die "cant open file: $!\n";
print FH "dummy data\n";
print FH "dummy data\n";     
print "child sleeping for 5 sec before exiting\n";
sleep 50;
exit;

}
else
{
print "entering the parent process\n";   
open FH, "<testfile.txt" or die "cant open file: $!\n";
 print <FH>;
 print <FH>;


}
```

---

Comment: Have you looked at using a pipe rather than a file? http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Bidirectional-Communication-with-Yourself

Comment: `sleep 50` isn't 50 seconds? Did you wait that long before you check your testfile?

Answer (score 2):

Parent process should wait at least fraction of second to allow child some time for writing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "creating file\n";
open my $FH, ">", "testfile.txt" or die "cant open file: $!\n";
close $FH;

my $pid = fork();

if ( $pid == 0 ) {
  print "entering in to child and opening file for write\n";
  open my $FH, ">>", "testfile.txt" or die "cant open file: $!\n";
  print $FH "dummy data\n";
  print $FH "dummy data\n";

  # print "child sleeping for 5 sec before exiting\n";
  # sleep 50;
  exit;
}
else {
  sleep 1;
  print "entering the parent process\n";
  open my $FH, "<", "testfile.txt" or die "cant open file: $!\n";
  print while <$FH>;
}
```

output

```
creating file
entering in to child and opening file for write
entering the parent process
dummy data
dummy data
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for helping me out with this problem. I was trying to resolve this yesterday and found an interesting thing about fork while using it with file handle for sharing data between child and parent i.e. we can resolve the problem with the following code and the trick is open the file handle before fork and inside the child just write to the file handle without reopening it. following is the  modified code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Fcntl qw(:flock SEEK_END);

print "creating file handle\n"; 
open my $FH, ">testfile.txt" or die "cant open file: $!\n";
#close FH;

my $pid = fork();

if ( $pid == 0 )
{
 print "entering in to child and opening file for write\n";
 #open FH, ">>testfile.txt" or die "cant open file: $!\n";

   # Put a exclusive lock in the filehandle for dening access to any other process   during this child process run
   flock($FH, LOCK_EX) or die "Cannot lock testfile.txt - $!\n";

   # and, in case someone appended while we were waiting...
   seek($FH, 0, SEEK_END) or die "Cannot seek - $!\n";



   # write data to temp file with exclusive lock on it   
    print $FH "dummy data\n";
    print $FH "dummy data\n";

   # remove the lock once writing is done
    flock($FH, LOCK_UN) or die "Cannot unlock temp.txt - $!\n";

 print "child sleeping for 5 sec before exiting\n";
 sleep 2;
 exit;

}
else
{
 print "entering the parent process\n"; 
 #flock(FH, LOCK_UN) or die "Cannot unlock temp.txt - $!\n";

 sleep 3;    
 open $FH, "<testfile.txt" or die "cant open file: $!\n";

 while (<$FH>){
 print "$_\n";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mpapec says, you are susceptible to a race condition where the parent reads from the file before the child has read from it. If you intend for the child process to produce output slowly and for the parent to process it relatively quickly, then the parent will frequently read past the end of file. You'll want to learn how to use `seek` to reset the end-of-file marker and wait for more input:

```
# parent process, after fork
sleep 1;         # give child time to create, write to file
open my $fh, '<', 'testfile.txt';
while (1) {

    my $line = <$fh>;
    if (defined($line)) {
        print $line;       # or  process($line)

        # another way (other than waitpid, see below) to see if the child is
        # finished is to use some convention between parent and child,
        # like having the child print "DONE!\n" as the last output it produces
        last if $line eq "DONE!\n";

    } else {

        # parent is starved for input. Is the child finished or is it just slow?
        use POSIX ':sys_wait_h';
        my $wpid = waitpid $pid, &WNOHANG;
        if ($wpid == $pid) {
            # child process has exited
            last;
        } else {
            # child is just slow. Clear the eof on $fh
            sleep 1;
            seek $fh, 0, 1;
        }
    }
}
close $fh;
```

The other thing you really ought to do is flush your output in the child process. Unless you are producing a lot of output very quickly, the output will spend time in a buffer and be inaccessible to the parent:

```
if ( $pid == 0 ) {
  print "entering in to child and opening file for write\n";
  open my $fh, ">>", "testfile.txt" or die "cant open file: $!\n";

  $fh->autoflush(1);          # force OS to send output to disk right away

  print $fh "dummy data\n";
  print $fh "dummy data\n";

  print "child sleeping for 5 sec before exiting\n";
  sleep 5.0;
  # print $fh "DONE!\n";
  close $fh;
  exit;
}
```

Interprocess communication is pretty tricky stuff to get right but also very powerful. Keep practicing.